# Smart Switch (Gosund) Install. Yes Power to box; No Green Light No Reset

Tags: wiring

Have successfully installed SW1. 
Basically same scenario  for SW2, EXCEPT: Power is at switch but nothing operable at switch. No Light of any kind, no manual operation, cannot Reset to try from square one. Bad switch, possibly three of four. FML?

Comment: Hi, for us to be able to advise anything, please do these: 1) provide a link to the user manual for said switch, 2) give as much detail as possible about the exact wiring map  you've applied. Where and how are you measuring "hot" AC power available, are neutrals at ground level, etc.

Comment: Does your smart switch require a neutral and are you *certain* that you have one in the box? A white wire is not necessarily a neutral wire.

Comment: A photo of what's in the switch box would help.  Do you mean that power comes to the switch, like, there are 2 cables with 2+ insulated wires each?  Are these 3-way switch locations?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box?

Comment: Too little information has been provided for us to be able to answer this.  DO NOT experiment with randomly connecting wires until stuff works.  The majority of combinations which will apparently work, will also kill you.